# Pandas Float Formatting

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I am a newbie to Python/Pandas and do not know how to present my dataframe.
I understand that the data may not need to be changed but rather how it is displayed.

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
                         min           max          mean
marketCap(EUR)  6.110331e+10  2.837429e+11  1.275993e+11
price(EUR)      3.679996e+03  1.694395e+04  7.538254e+03
generatedCoins  1.000000e+03  2.437500e+03  1.921524e+03
paymentCount    2.386370e+05  8.086800e+05  4.019127e+05
min     float64
max     float64
mean    float64
dtype: object
```

but would like it to be displayed as follow:

```
                   min       max     average
marketcap(EUR)    61.10    283.74     127.59
price(EUR)      3679.99  16943.95    7538.25
generatedCoins  1000.00   2437.50    1921.52
paymentCount  238637.00 808680.00  401912.66
```

What do I need to change to format my output as desired?

This is the code I used for the dataframe:

```
ResultDataFrameEUR = pd.DataFrame(0, index=['marketCap(EUR)','price(EUR)','generatedCoins','paymentCount'], columns = ['min','max','mean'])  #Create new DataFrame for Output and fill it with 0
ResultDataFrameEUR.loc['marketCap(EUR)'] = BtcDataFrameEUR['marketCap(EUR)'].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
ResultDataFrameEUR.loc['price(EUR)'] = BtcDataFrameEUR['price(EUR)'].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
ResultDataFrameEUR.loc['generatedCoins'] = BtcDataFrameEUR['generatedCoins'].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
ResultDataFrameEUR.loc['paymentCount'] = BtcDataFrameEUR['paymentCount'].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the display option for floats:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format

print(df)
#                          min             max            mean
#marketCap(EUR) 61103310000.00 283742900000.00 127599300000.00
#price(EUR)            3680.00        16943.95         7538.25
#generatedCoins        1000.00         2437.50         1921.52
#paymentCount        238637.00       808680.00       401912.70
```

It seems like you also want to disply the first row in billions, so do:

```
df.loc['marketCap(EUR)'] = df.loc['marketCap(EUR)']/10**9

#                     min       max      mean
#marketCap(EUR)     61.10    283.74    127.60
#price(EUR)       3680.00  16943.95   7538.25
#generatedCoins   1000.00   2437.50   1921.52
#paymentCount   238637.00 808680.00 401912.70
```

Or perhaps don't change the data and add `,` to separate every 3 orders of magintude:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

#                             min                max               mean
#marketCap(EUR) 61,103,310,000.00 283,742,900,000.00 127,599,300,000.00
#price(EUR)              3,680.00          16,943.95           7,538.25
#generatedCoins          1,000.00           2,437.50           1,921.52
#paymentCount          238,637.00         808,680.00         401,912.70
```

Comment: incredible ! Thanks @Alollz. 
On 2 occasions the float has been rounded "3680.00" instead of "3679.99" and "127.60" instead of "127.59", Why is that so ?

Comment: @forceorange because they are really 3679.996, the extra thousandths digit makes the rounding go up.